# How to copy some data from Chrome Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a web page with some data that I want to extract
So I open Chrome Developpers Console and type:

```
$x('//a[contains(@class, "link-class")]/text()')
```

but I've got:

```
[text, text, text]
```

instead of list of strings. Is there any to get list of strins that I can copy to my notepad, excel etc?

Answer (score 5):

Within the console you can actually just type `copy('some data')` and it will copy to your clipboard.  You will still have to format the information first.

**Try this**:

```
const formatted = JSON.stringify($x('//a[contains(@class, "link-class")]/text()').map((a) => a.data));

copy(formatted);
```

Comment: @MrGeek Does this log out the proper information? `console.dir($x('//a[contains(@class, "link-class")]/text()'))`

Comment: No, you should add a map `$x(...).map((a) => a.data))`.

Comment: You know you can test this in this page, just change the class from `link-class` to `post-tag` and test in your console.

Comment: Yep, I originally thought the idea was to copy the whole object.

Answer (score 4):

$x() returns DOM elements (in this case text nodes), so you need a step to extract the string from inside. You might have more luck with

```
$x('//a[contains(@class, "link-class")]').map( elt => elt.innerText );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array.forEach(..)` method to go through the DOM elements returned by `$x()` and log their data:

```
$x('//a[contains(@class, "link-class")]/text()').forEach((a) => console.log(a.data))
```

For a string of texts separated with `\n` use:

```
$x('//a[contains(@class, "link-class")]/text()').map((a) => a.data).join('\n')
```

Comment: Your code work. But how can I join it all to one console post?

Comment: @GhostKU You want an array of texts?

Comment: I want string of texts divided with '\n'

Answer (score 2):

if you have an array and want to pretty print it, you could simply do:

```
console.log(arr.join("\n"));
```

in your case then

```
console.log(
  $x('//a[contains(@class, "link-class")]/text()')
    .map(el => el.innerText)
    .join("\n")
);
```

you could also format them like:

```
console.log(arr.map((el, ix) => ix + " : " + el.innerText).join("\n"));
```

to get:

0 : text1

1 : text2

Comment: It is great idea to get all data in one console post divided with '\n' but when I use your code I get list of [object Text] lines on my console.

Comment: the `.map(el => el.innerText)` was missing, to get the text out of the dom element.

Comment: Than we should remove `/text()` Right?